# Triggering a Mako command from the view depending on a simple calculation

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyramid

I have **n number of def blocks** in my **inheriting template** which shows one of them in the inherited template depending on a variable value which is passed from the view.

Currently, I do the computing in the View file, then there decide which def to be visible, then pass this in a dictionary as a key-value along with other to-be-shown data to the inheriting template and there, using **`if-elif-endif`** clause evaluate this key's value to see which def to show and then manually call that def with **`**${self.val_of_key_nn()}**`**

I want to know if there is a way to get rid of this if-elif-endif bock and simply pass the **`self.def_to_call()`** command to the template directly from the view?

example code:

```
#defs is a key in the passed-dictionary.
#I want to reduce this block to a single-line code
% if defs == '1':  
${self.block_1()}
% elif defs == '2':
${self.block_2()}
% else:
${self.block_default()}
% endif
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possibly the inheritance part is making the question less clear, when it's really a question about letting the view-callable determine which def will be rendered from the template.  Might be worth it to rewrite to simplify that.  Although perhaps I'm missing part of the importance.

Comment: Hello cdaddr, I surely can edit the question to eliminate the nesting-inheriting part. However, this is vital for my needs as I have a main template that all my site-app uses and I have for each section, an inheriting template where defs of that particular section of the site are located. This setup increases re-usability and readability for me. ;-) If you believe it would help others more to eliminate that part, I will follow suit.

Comment: I don't know, that's up to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phil, your question is most timely... as of June 2012 they are working on making this ability more explicit for a future Pyramid version.

There is a way to do it currently, but it's undocumented, and if you use it you should consider it liable to change in the future.  Instead of returning only a dict from your view callable, return a tuple:
`('defname', {...})`  where `'defname'` is the (quoted) name of the specific def that you wish to render, and `{...}` is the dict as usual.

If you're interested in the proposed future method for this, which puts the defname in the template path (asset spec) instead:

https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/commit/ea009a6d4a1ffa8585faa85581848f6e74a57dfc

FYI for other interested readers: there's an excellent post on use cases for this technique on zzzeek's blog [here](http://techspot.zzzeek.org/2012/06/18/server-side-templates-and-api-centric-development/).

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```py
<%
    defdict = {'1': block_1, '2': block_2}
%>

${defdict.get(defs, block_default)()}
```

Comment: Hello. This is not to do with my question. I am wondering about how to pass a command ({self.block_name()}) from the view to the template. Thank you.